# Family visitor visa refusal

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image: visa refusal letter 1][image: visitors visa refusal letter 2] visitor visa-refusals refusal.my father has given 300,000 to his friend and friend paid him back in three transaction of 100,000.can some body tell me  how to prove that.it all done by cheque.

Comment: The refusal notice says that in the application your father stated he had no savings or investments, yet he submitted bank statements showing a balance of almost £3,600 equivalent. These two ‘facts’ don’t reconcile. He would need to prove where he originally got the money from to lend to his friend, however his chances of success after two refusals are very probably minimal.

Comment: "Retired, with no source of income and no savings" doesn't bode well, no matter whether the origin-of-funds issue can be cleared up or not.

Comment: All money was transferred from my UK bank account to his account originally then he lend money to his friend. After few months he paid back

Comment: I have provided all proof for that and in bank account it does state my name when money credited